# Как пройтись по pandas.Dataframe и изменить данные?

Tags: python, pandas

По api получаю большой объект `list<class>`. Дальше загоняю его в `pandas`

```
leads = b.get_all(
   'tasks.task.list',
    params={
    'select': ['*', 'UF_*']
})

df = pd.DataFrame(leads)
```

Колонок штук `50`. Я хочу пройтись по элементам каждой колонки и убрать оттуда символы `['`,`']`,`[]`,`[`,`]`

ps В конце буду выгружать в Excel

Comment: Воспроизводимый пример датафрейма добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Удобнее всего воспользоваться методом `replace` с параметром `regex=True` :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['[Иванов', 'Петров]', "['Сидоров"], 'col2': ['иванов[]', 'текст', 'иванов']})
df = df.replace("[]|[|]|['|']",'', regex=True)
df
```